# Positional association cannot follow named association

Tags: vhdl

I have implemnted Carry Select Adder using D-lATCh. But I am Getting the following error.

> HDLCompiler:720 - "/home/aabhinav/Downloads/Example/CSA_4bits/CSA_BEC1.vhd" Line 76: Positional association cannot follow named association
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "/home/aabhinav/Downloads/Example/CSA_4bits/CSA_BEC1.vhd" Line 41: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

Below is my attached code. If anyone could help me as I am new to VHDL and doing my school project.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    17:08:00 11/16/2016 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    CSA_BEC1 - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity CSA_BEC1 is
port( A,B : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cin : in std_logic;
        Scsa : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));

end CSA_BEC1;

architecture Behavioral of CSA_BEC1 is

COMPONENT d_latch_top is
   port( A : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); 
            EN : IN STD_LOGIC;
         B : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)); 
end COMPONENT;



COMPONENT MUX10_5 is
    PORT(X, Y: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            sel: in std_logic;
          m: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end COMPONENT;

component rc_adder
    Port ( X : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Y : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
--            Cin: in STD_LOGIC ;
           sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Carry : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;


signal RCSum: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 3 DOWNTO 0);
signal BECSum, M: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 4 DOWNTO 0);
signal RCCarry,BECCarry: STD_LOGIC;
signal RC_S_C: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 4 DOWNTO 0);


begin

RC: rc_adder PORT MAP(X => A, Y => B, SUM => RCSum, Carry => RCCarry);
RC_S_C <= RCCarry&RCSum;
dlatch: d_latch_top PORT MAP(A => RC_S_C,B => BECSum, EN = '1');
MUX: MUX10_5 PORT MAP(X => BECSum, y => RC_S_C , sel => cin, m => Scsa);


end Behavioral;



----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    17:19:36 11/16/2016 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    rc_adder - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity rc_adder is
port(   X : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  --4 bit input 1
            Y :  in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- 4 bit input 2
--              Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
            sum : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);   -- 4 bit sum
           carry :  out std_logic   -- carry out.
);
end rc_adder;

architecture logic of rc_adder is

COMPONENT full_adder is
    port (a : in std_logic;
            b : in std_logic;
           cin : in std_logic;
           sum : out std_logic;
           carry : out std_logic
         );
end COMPONENT;

signal C0: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 2 DOWNTO 0);

begin
FA1: full_adder PORT MAP(X(0),Y(0),'0',sum(0),C0(0));
FA2: full_adder PORT MAP(X(1),Y(1),C0(0),sum(1),C0(1));
FA3: full_adder PORT MAP(X(2),Y(2),C0(1),sum(2),C0(2));
FA4: full_adder PORT MAP(X(3),Y(3),C0(2),sum(3),Carry);

end logic;
```

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity d_latch_top is
    Port ( A  : in  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
           EN : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B  : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end d_latch_top;

architecture Behavioral of d_latch_top is
    signal DATA : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin

    DATA <= A when (EN = '1') else DATA;
    B <= DATA;

end Behavioral;
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    17:54:06 11/12/2016 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    MUX10_5 - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
entity MUX10_5 is
    PORT( X, Y: in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
            sel: in std_logic;
          m: out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0));
end MUX10_5;

architecture logic of MUX10_5 is

    component MUX6_3 is
        PORT( sel: in std_logic;
              X, Y: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
              m: out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0));
    end component;
   
    component MUX4_2 is
        PORT( sel, X0, X1, Y0, Y1: in std_logic;
              m0, m1: out std_logic);
    end component;
   
begin

    mux6_3_inst0 : MUX6_3
    PORT MAP( sel => sel, X => X(2 downto 0), Y => Y(2 downto 0),
              m => m(2 downto 0));
             
    mux4_2_inst0 : MUX4_2
    PORT MAP( sel => sel, X0 => X(3), X1 => X(4), Y0 => Y(3), Y1 => Y(4),
              m0 => m(3), m1 => m(4));
             
end logic;
```

Comment: We're not your personal debugging service.

Comment: This is not an [MCVE] - you could usefully have trimmed a few pages of unnecessary commented out stuff and brought it down to a few lines. I'm not going to count through this mess to find line 76.

Answer (score 1):

See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1 General, para 5:

> Named associations can be given in any order, but if both positional and named associations appear in the same association list, then all positional associations shall occur first at their normal position. Hence once a named association is used, the rest of the association list shall use only named associations.

In the architecture for CSA_BEC1, the component instantiation labeled `dlatch`, pretty much where the first error message said. The named association malformed: `EN = '1'` should be `EN => '1'`.

A VHDL parser can be implemented LALR(1), meaning it doesn't need to look ahead beyond the next token.  You might imagine someone was using the compound delimiter "=>" to determine whether or not an association item is named or positional. It seems it's not smart enough to give a separate error message when the following delimiter ("="), wasn't a ',' or a ')' for the last item in an association list.

Such 'luxuries' usually show up with tool implementation maturity. Fee free to allow the vendor to know the error message is not particularly enlightening.